# Oracle finding the common location between different restriction "codes"

Tags: oracle

this is my first question here. I need to basically find the common location between different restriction codes for an ingredient number.The restriction codes and locations reside in their own table.
My current query returns something like this (there is more data to this but it is not needed for this question)

```
ingredient_number   restriction_code
-----------------   -------------------
 001                NN
 001                R-03
 001                R-02
 002                R-22
 002                NN
 003                R-03
```

The table with all of the restrictions and their locations looks like this

```
restriction_code   location
----------------   --------
NN                 CLE
NN                 LAX
NN                 ORD
NN                 JFK
NN                 PIT
NN                 DFW
R-03               CLE
R-03               LAX
R-02               LAX
R-02               DFW
R-22               JFK
R-03               PIT
```

I need to have the results look like this

```
ingredient_number  restriction_code common_loc
-----------------  ---------------- ----------
001                NN               LAX
001                R-03             LAX
001                R-02             LAX
002                R-22             JFK
002                NN               JFK
003                R-03             PIT
```

LAX is common to all three of the restriction codes so we pick that one in this example.

I am guessing that I will need to use an inner join to join the common locations, but I am at a loss for how to figure that out. Any help would be greatly appreciated! I just need pointed in the right direction.

Comment: What are the actual table names and have you tried anything you can share?

Comment: Since for a given ingredient_number you must have ALL restrictions in the same location, what is the point of presenting the output in that manner? It would suffice to simply show the ingredient_number **once**, with the common location for all restriction codes. Then: What should happen if there is more than one common location? What if all restriction codes for an ingredient can be found both at LAX and at LGA? What if for an ingredient there is **no** common location - should you still show *something* for that ingredient?

Comment: For example: For ingredient 003, with a single restriction code of R-03, there are three locations where that restriction code is found. Why do you only include one of them in your output?

Comment: @mathguy So not to go into too much detail, but the locations are basically a stand in for my steel suppliers. The reason it has to show each ingredient_number is that in part of the query that I already have written it breaks down the demand in pounds for each restriction code. I also will have a table of weights for each location based on the restriction code that will solve the problem where there are three locations for one restriction code. Also, If there were to be no common location it can just be null.

Comment: OK, I will edit my Answer to show how you can get what you need. Instead of GROUP BY I need to use analytic COUNT for both counts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way, finding all locations where all restriction codes for a given ingredient can be found. If for an ingredient there is no single location where all restrictions can be found, that ingredient will be **excluded** from the output. If for an ingredient there are multiple locations where all the restriction codes for that ingredient can be found, then ALL those locations are shown in the output.

It's a bit silly to repeat all the restriction codes for an ingredient in the **output** of the query; I show a single row for each (ingredient_number, location) that satisfies your condition.

Setup:

```
create table restriction_codes (ingredient_number, restriction_code) as
    select '001', 'NN'   from dual union all
    select '001', 'R-03' from dual union all
    select '001', 'R-02' from dual union all
    select '002', 'R-22' from dual union all
    select '002', 'NN'   from dual union all
    select '003', 'R-03' from dual union all
    select '004', 'CCC'  from dual union all
    select '004', 'DDD'  from dual
;

create table locations (restriction_code, location) as
    select 'NN'  , 'CLE' from dual union all
    select 'NN'  , 'LAX' from dual union all
    select 'NN'  , 'ORD' from dual union all
    select 'NN'  , 'JFK' from dual union all
    select 'NN'  , 'PIT' from dual union all
    select 'NN'  , 'DFW' from dual union all
    select 'R-03', 'CLE' from dual union all
    select 'R-03', 'LAX' from dual union all
    select 'R-02', 'LAX' from dual union all
    select 'R-02', 'DFW' from dual union all
    select 'R-22', 'JFK' from dual union all
    select 'R-03', 'PIT' from dual union all
    select 'CCC' , 'ORD' from dual union all
    select 'DDD' , 'LGA' from dual
;
```

Query and output:

```
with
  prep (ingredient_number, restriction_code, restriction_count) as (
    select ingredient_number, restriction_code, 
           count(*) over (partition by ingredient_number)
    from   restriction_codes
  )
select p.ingredient_number, l.location
from   prep p inner join locations l on p.restriction_code = l.restriction_code
group  by p.ingredient_number, p.restriction_count, l.location
having count(*) = p.restriction_count
order  by p.ingredient_number, l.location
;

INGREDIENT_NUMBER  LOCATION
------------------ --------
001                LAX     
002                JFK     
003                CLE     
003                LAX     
003                PIT
```

**EDIT**  -  The OP clarified that he does indeed need to show all the input rows in the output (one row for each restriction code for the (ingredient, location) pairs that satisfy the requirement).

Here is how that can be done:

```
select ingredient_number, restriction_code, location
from   (
         select r.ingredient_number, r.restriction_code, l.location,
                count(distinct r.restriction_code) 
                    over (partition by r.ingredient_number) as global_ct,
                count(r.restriction_code) 
                    over (partition by r.ingredient_number, l.location) as local_ct
         from   restriction_codes r inner join locations l 
                                    on r.restriction_code = l.restriction_code
       )
where  global_ct = local_ct
order  by ingredient_number, location, restriction_code
;

INGREDIENT_NUMBER  RESTRICTION_CODE   LOCATION
------------------ ------------------ --------
001                NN                 LAX     
001                R-02               LAX     
001                R-03               LAX     
002                NN                 JFK     
002                R-22               JFK     
003                R-03               CLE     
003                R-03               LAX     
003                R-03               PIT
```

Comment: thank you so much this solution worked for me. I just forgot to give you the accepted answer!

Answer (score 0):

Using a common table expression join the two tables.  Then join the CTE to itself based on location.  Now if more than 1 location is shared, you'll get multiples per ingredient.

```
WITH CTE AS (T1.Ingredient_Number, T1.Restriction_Code, T2.Location
SELECT *
FROM T1
INNER JOIN T2
 on T1.Restriction_Code = T2.Restriction_Code)

SELECT A.Ingredient_Number, A.Restriction_Code
FROM CTE A
INNE JOIN CTE B
  on A.Ingredient_Number = B.Ingredient_Number
 and A.Location = B.Location
```

Comment: Besides obvious syntax errors:  `with cte as (SELECT something-or-other)`, I wonder how this will find locations where all restriction codes for an ingredient can be found. An ingredient may have five restrictions - you must find a location where all five of those restriction can be found. How will your code do that?